# NET MAUI Application Display Version value incorrect

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, maui, blazor-hybrid

I am using my NET MAUI project properties > MAUI Shared > General > Application Display Version to set app version (example below):

[image]

However, when I call:

```cs
AppInfo.Current.Version.ToString()
```

On my app about page the value is always '1.0.0'.

Am I not using the correct setting?

**Edit:**

Actually looks like my issue was related to deployment on 'iOS Local Device'. I tested on Android emulator and seeing the correct values:

[Android Emulator]
[image]

[iOS Local Device]
[image]

I am learning testing on 'iOS Local Device' does not deploy a lot of features: splash images, icon, and looks like some app info.

Edit 2:

Filed issue on MAUI repo:
https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/20000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case I was not seeing the correct Application Display Version value only when deploying to 'iOS Local Device'. Tested on 'Android Emulator' and correct value displays.

I am learning testing on 'iOS Local Device' does not deploy a lot of features: app custom splash images, app custom icon, and looks like some app info.

Hope this saves someone time in case they run into the same scenario.

Comment: Filed issue on MAUI repo: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/20000

Answer (score 2):

According to the docs 
[Application display version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/macios/info-plist?view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=vs#application-display-version):

> The application display version for a .NET MAUI app is stored in the
> app's project file as the `ApplicationDisplayVersion` build property.
>
> When the value of the **Application Display Version field** is
> updated, the value of the Version field in the application view in the
> `Info.plist` file will be automatically updated.

And it could be a potential issue or a limitation to correctly get the value of `AppInfo.Current.Version` only when deploying to **iOS Local Device**, Android works fine. You can report it to Github:https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues and hopefully this will be fixed soon.

Hope this clarifies a little bit!

Comment: May Thanks for the reply! I will report the issue on the MAUI repo. I am guessing that the issue may be related to how iOS Local Device gets deployed to iPhone from Windows Visual Studio...I do not think it does a full xcode build etc.

Comment: Filed issue on MAUI repo: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/20000

Comment: @seanrco Thanks for the response, hopefully it'll be fixed soon.

Answer (score 1):

You are in the right place, you can try to clean solution then run again.
This is my illustration:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Turns out my issue was related to deploying on 'iOS Local Device'. Tested on Android Emulator and see correct value. Will update with answer in case anyone else runs into this.